# Is this sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left({1\over kx}+{1\over kx-1}+{1\over kx-2}+\cdots+{1\over kx-x+1}-\ln{k+1\over k}\right)=\gamma+\ln{x}$ correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, euler-mascheroni-constant

Given that:

$\mbox{A well-known Euler's sum is}\displaystyle\quad%
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[{1\over k} - \ln\left(k + 1 \over k\right)\right] =
\gamma\label{1}\tag{1}
$
The generalised of \eqref{1} is:

> $$
> \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[{1 \over kx} + {1 \over kx - 1} +
> {1 \over kx - 2} + \cdots + {1 \over kx - x + 1} -
> \ln\left(k + 1\over k\right)\right] = \gamma + \ln\left(x\right)\label{2}\tag{2}
> $$

Where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant and $x \geq 1$.

**Is the sum of \eqref{2} correct ?**

Comment: It's not even correct for $x=1$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Not true at all. when $x=1$ the LHS becomes simply $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left({1\over k}-\ln{k+1\over k}\right)$$ which is the OP's identity already stated

Comment: Sorry, let me check again

Comment: Numerically, this seems correct, at least for $x=1$ and $x=2$. Now, some work is needed to define this for non-integer values of $x$

Comment: Where is this conjecture from

Comment: Note that $$\log(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left[\sum\limits_{j=1}^{x-1}\frac{1}{kx-j}-\frac{x-1}{kx}\right]$$

Comment: $(2)$ came from $(1)$ base on an observation I made.

Comment: The formula given by @Brevan Ellefsen has a nice interpretation as the rearrangement R(x,1) (x positive terms, 1 negative term) of the null harmonic series
log(1) = (1-1)+(1/2-1/2)+(1/3-1/3)+...
In general, the rearrangement R(p,q) converges to log(p/q).
$$
\log\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=pi+1}^{p(i+1)}\frac{1}{j}-\sum_{k=qi+1}^{q(i+1)}\frac{1}{k}\right)
$$

Comment: See, for example, how to build log(3/2) http://oeis.org/A166711

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that $x$ is a positive integer. Note that $$\sum_{m=0}^{x-1}\frac{1}{kx-m}=H_{kx}-H_{x\left(k-1\right)}$$ where $H_{l}$ is the $l$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(H_{n}-\log\left(n\right)\right)=\gamma$$ we have $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{x-1}\frac{1}{kx-m}-\log\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\right)\right)$$ $$=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(H_{kx}-H_{x\left(k-1\right)}-\log\left(k+1\right)+\log\left(k\right)\right)\right)$$ $$=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(H_{Nx}-\log\left(N\right)\right)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(H_{Nx}-\log\left(Nx\right)+\log\left(x\right)\right)=\color{red}{\gamma+\log\left(x\right)}.$$

Comment: How did you go from $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(H_{kx}-H_{x\left(k-1\right)}-\log\left(k+1\right)+\log\left(k\right)\right)\right)$$ to $$=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(H_{Nx}-\log\left(N\right)\right)$$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen It is a telescopic sum.